# Stripe checkout on wizard page via wicked gem gives error on loading, how to resolve?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, wicked-gem

Right now I get this error message when the submit.html.erb loads: `Cannot charge a customer that has no active card`.

I want to understand how I can improve my controller. The goal is to not have the error message when the submit page loads. But only if there's an actual user submitting false information.

```
class SubmissionsController < ApplicationController
include Wicked::Wizard
steps :name, :details, :comments, :submit, :thankyou

def show
  @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
  render_wizard
end

def update
  @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])

  # one time checkout
  @amount = 50
  @description = 'Premium Package'

  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => params[:stripeEmail],
    :source  => params[:stripeToken]
  )

  Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => customer.id,
    :amount      => @amount,
    :description => @description,
    :currency    => 'eur'
  )

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message

  params[:company][:status] = step.to_s
  params[:company][:status] = 'active' if step == steps.last
  @company.update_attributes(company_params)
  render_wizard @company
end

private ...
```

Here's the submit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @company, url: wizard_path, method: :put do |f| %>
  <article>
    <% if flash[:error].present? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <p><%= flash[:error] %></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <label class="amount">
      <span>Amount: €0.50</span>
    </label>
  </article>

  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
          data-description=<% @description %>
          data-amount=<% @amount %>
          data-locale="auto"></script>
<% end %>
```

If I can provide more context, please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactored into this, now it works:

```
class SubmissionsController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard
  steps :name, :details, :comments, :submit, :thankyou

  def show
    get_company
    set_package
    render_wizard
  end

  def update
    case step
    when :thankyou
      get_company
      render_wizard @company
    when :submit
      get_company
      set_package
      if request.put?
        create_customer
        do_payment
        render_wizard @company
      end
    else
      get_company
      params[:company][:status] = 'active' if step == steps.last
      @company.update_attributes(company_params)
      render_wizard @company
    end
  end

  def get_company
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
  end

  def create_customer
    @customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :email => params[:stripeEmail],
      :source  => params[:stripeToken]
    )
  end

  def set_package
    @amount = 50
    @amount_in_decimals = @amount / 100.00
    @description = "Premium Package"
  end

  def do_payment
    Stripe::Charge.create(
      :customer    => @customer.id,
      :amount      => @amount,
      :description => @description,
      :currency    => "eur"
    )

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
  end
```

and for the view

```
    <label class="amount">
      <span>Amount: <%= number_to_currency(@amount_in_decimals, :precision => 2, :locale => :nl) %></span>
    </label>
  </article>

  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
          data-name="RailsApp!"
          data-description='<%= @description %>'
          data-amount=<%= @amount %>
          data-locale="auto"
          data-currency="eur"></script>
<% end %>
```